# Why CSS selector can't have empty space but Xpath can?

Tags: python, css, xpath, playwright-python

I have a HTML element with a class attribute that contains empty spaces.

How come Xpath can find this element can CSS can not?

```
# Element: <div class="I Love StackOverFlow"></div>

self.page.locator('//div[@class="I Love StackOverFlow"]') # works
self.page.locator('div[class="I love StackOverFlow"]' # Fails
```

How can I make the CSS selector find the element with white / empty spaces?

Comment: HTML class names can't have white spaces in them. HTML sees names separated by white spaces as separate class names.

Comment: Do you mean to have an uppercase C in the Class?

Comment: @AHaworth No, this was a type I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class name with spaces is actually not a single class name value but several values.
In your example there are 3 values `I` and `Love` and `StackOverFlow`.
So, to locate that element with CSS Selector you can instead of `self.page.locator('div[Class="I love StackOverFlow"]')`
write it more correctly:

```py
self.page.find_element_by_css_selector('div.I.love.StackOverFlow')
```

Comment: And what do I do if the class contains dots?

Comment: @TalAngel Escape it with a \. Make sure to check for browser support though.

Comment: I'm not sure I ever faced this ever.